# Could not transfer artifact com.mobidevelop.robovm

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

While executing Gradle task ios:CreateIPA getting the below error.

```
    Execution failed for task ':ios:createIPA'.
> Could not transfer artifact com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-dist:tar.gz:nocompiler:2.3.3 from/to maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mobidevelop/robovm/robovm-dist/2.3.3/robovm-dist-2.3.3-nocompiler.tar.gz. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
```

Anybody encountered this issue? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.3.3 version is quite old. you should update to 2.3.9 or 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT where this issue was fixed

Comment: I have updated to 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT and IPA creation is happening.